# Javascript clientHeight returns correct values in devtools console but 0 from js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi for some reason when I try to get client Height of an element via javascript file it returns 0, both ways via javascript (element.clientHeight) and jquery ($("element").height();) . But when I ask height of the same element via console it returns the correct value. Why is it happening. Thx.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        var obj = document.getElementById("slider").clientHeight;
        console.log(obj);
    });
});
```

Comment: I would guess that the `#slider` element is not part of the DOM when the DOMReady event fires, and is added to the page later. Also, having a `window.load` handler inside a `document.ready` handler is redundant.

Comment: Whether the slider contents are dynamically added?

Comment: Yes they are via lazy load with nivo slider. How the height can be detected then?

Comment: add your code in side $(window).load(function(){})

Comment: @Juhana in his code dont need to add document ready function ?

Comment: @AndriusSolopovas The slider probably exposes some event for when the contents are loaded. You'll have to bind the code to that.

Comment: Nivo slider seems to have a hook that fires when the slider is built `afterLoad `. You may pass a function to it.

Answer (score -1):

First, try to remove load (or ready) function like that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var obj = document.getElementById("slider").clientHeight;
   console.log(obj);
});
```

or that:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   var obj = document.getElementById("slider").clientHeight;
   console.log(obj);
});
```

Otherwite the two functions are waiting eachother the end of load.

Comment: Ok, what is your slider ?